# AIR - Video Seeking with Pseudo-streaming

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have created a scrubber for streaming video in an AIR application. It works with short videos, but with the longer videos it does not work.

**The problem** is how to make the `seek()` method go to a specific time without a need to fully buffer the video data?

thanks:

```
var _duration:Number;
var _scrubbing:Boolean;

//-------------------- download and add the video ----------------------------//

var nC:NetConnection = new NetConnection ();
nC.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nC);
ns.play("")

var vid:Video = new Video();
vid.attachNetStream(ns);
addChild(vid);


vid.width = v_container.width;
vid.height = v_container.height;
vid.smoothing = true;

var client:Object = new Object(); 
client.onMetaData = onMetaData; 
ns.client = client;             


function onMetaData(metaData:Object):void
{
    _duration = metaData.duration;  
}

//--------------------  creat playhead and lesten to mouse event--------------------------//

drag.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,drag_To_Position);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,_stop_drag_To_Position);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,calculate_position);

function drag_To_Position(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    drag.startDrag(false,new Rectangle(bar.x,bar.y,bar.width - drag.width,0));
    _scrubbing = true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------//

function _stop_drag_To_Position(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    drag.stopDrag();
    _scrubbing = false ;

}

//----------------- seek method & specific time ------------------//

function calculate_position(e:Event):void
{

    if ( _duration > 0 )
    {
        if ( _scrubbing == true )
        {
            ns.seek( _duration * drag.x / bar.width );
            var posi:Number = Math.floor((bar.x - drag.x) / (drag.width  - bar.width) * 100 );
            pro.gotoAndStop(posi);
        }
        else
        {
            var seckto:Number = Math.floor((bar.x - drag.x) / (drag.width  - bar.width) * 100 );
            drag.x = ns.time / _duration * bar.width ; 
            pro.gotoAndStop(seckto)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to setup a streaming server

Comment: Sorry I missed the detail about AIR, I thought it was a web app and suggested PHP. Yes AIR can achieve same thing to extract later bytes from a file before download has reached them. You still need to use `appendBytes` method to play those bytes (start from nearest FLV keyframe position). WIth bytes you seek to a byte position not time position. But each frame has a timestamp (write code to check timestamp etc). It's complicated to do manually without video programming experience. Also `seek()` does not work with `appendBytes` since you control bytes & time manually yourself...

Comment: VC.One thank you ... i will try to do what you suggestet . And add my code later . Best regard